# Using the VHF port for 6m on an Icom IC-706mkIIg transceiver

Tags: antenna-system, equipment, icom

My Icom IC-706mkIIg transceiver has two output ports:

- one for its VHF/UHF bands (i.e. 2m/70cm)
- one for the HF bands, and also 6m!

I have a couple of broadband VHF/UHF antennas whose transmit specs include the 6m (50MHz) band, so I'd rather have the 6m band output on the VHF/UHF port. I understand for example that the Yaesu FT-817ND allows some configuration of which bands use which of *its* two ports, but do not see anything similar in my Icom's menu settings.

Is there any modification available to move 6m handling to the IC-706mk2g's VHF port, whether a setting I've missed, a jumper inside, or even some minor circuitry rework?

Otherwise could I accomplish this without undue loss — or expense! — via some combination of diplexers and/or other filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't find a solution based on modifying the radio, this is a reasonable use for two diplexers. You can, in principle, hook them up two different ways:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftp8hw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These two configurations have in theory the same requirements for the two diplexers — one which separates 30− and 50+ MHz and one which separates 54− and 144+ MHz. However, the second configuration has two advantages:

- It should have less insertion loss at other than 50 MHz, since the other bands pass through only one diplexer and not two.
- The bottom left diplexer deals only with frequencies 54 MHz and below, — it does not need to have good performance at UHF.

A brief search (I didn't check all the specifications in detail) shows that suitable duplexers are available from several brands (Comet, Diamond and MFJ) for prices around US $60-80 each.

Comment: Thanks! Your first example is embarrassingly obvious now that I've seen it, and the second is a nice optimization. I'll have to take a look at which duplexers are more commonly available, although my initial research is turning up commercial duplexers up in the same price range as a second discone!

Comment: @natevw-AF7TB Not sure what you mean by "more commonly available" — both solutions require the same two diplexers. I'm seeing prices around US \$70 each, so \$140 for the pair. The _lowest cost_ solution might be to use just one HF/6 duplexer and put up a separate, simple 6 meter antenna, certainly. (Don't forget to count the price of the feed line…)